# batch file - loop to append strings to variable

Tags: batch-file

How come this keep replacing the variable with each data from the loop instead of appending it?

```
set ipList=
for /F %%i in (ips.txt) do ( set ipList=%ipLis%,%%i )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's true you need delayed expansion. Another way:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set ipList=
for /F %%i in (ips.txt) do ( set ipList=!ipList!,%%i )
```

Note the '!' instead of '%%'. Also, there was a typo in your question, I suppose it should be %%ipList%% instead of %%ipLis%% (a 't' is lacking).

Answer (score 3):

You need delayedexpansion or this technique:

```
set ipList=
for /F "delims=" %%i in (ips.txt) do call set "ipList=%%ipList%%,%%i"
```